# "No information is available for this page" says google for WP site

Tags: wordpress, google-console-developer, yoast

for my site google console has stooped to read the site and when search in google it says "No information is available for this page." how can we solve this does anyone help me out? here is the screenshot:https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkvxs.png

Comment: it the website till working fine? - if so, maybe check your robots.txt if you deny the googlebots access.

Comment: @Stender here is the link of robots.txt:https://nepaljapan.com/robots.txt there is no such denay also

Answer (score 0):

What do you see in "Learn why"? Maybe this could help?

1. Open your site’s file by visiting www.yourdomainname.com/robots.txt
2. Investigate all “Disallow” messages. The most common problem is “Disallow: /” which actually tells search engine crawlers to never crawl any pages on your site.
3. Use Google Search Console’s Robots.txt checker tool on problem pages to confirm any “Disallow” messaging impact.
4. Use Google Search Console’s “Fetch as Google” tool on problem pages to confirm Google crawlers (desktop and mobile) can access site content and render on their end.
5. Ensure your site does not have multiple or cached robots.txt version – Check https vs. http, www. vs non-www, or old robots versions that Google (and other engines) may still be referencing.

Comment: found it here: http://www.davebuesing.com/my-google-search-results-say-no-information-available-but-im-not-blocking-via-robots-txt-whats-up/

Comment: What is the url of Google Search Console’s Robots.txt checker tool of new google console